# Redirecting localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/newpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and wondering how I can route a button on click to a new page. This is what my App looks like now. I am posting an object to the server and then I am hoping to go to a new page. Right now I am running this app on localhost:3000 and I want to route to localhost:3000/orders.

```
class App extends Component {

  placeOrder = () => {
      let {cupcakes, startDate, orders} = this.state;

      const order = {
        cupcakes: cupcakes,
        delivery_date: startDate.toISOString()
      } 

      const newOrder = [...orders, order]
      this.setState({orders: newOrder})

      fetch('http://localhost:4000/cupcakes/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(orders)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          if(response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
        }).then(function(responseBody){
            console.log(responseBody)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Request failed", error);
        });
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={this.placeOrder}>Place Order</button>
  }

}
```

Comment: take a look at react router

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate from your front end you would need to implement that with your React Router or whatever you are using for navigation.  I don't know how you have your front end navigation setup to help with that.

An alternative would be to implement it in your backend depending how you are structuring your front end.  Something like `res.redirect('/orders')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest (but not best, react router is really useful) redirect, you can just do `window.location.href = http://localhost:3000/orders`.